# Eclair Lightning network node is not public

Tags: lightning-network, eclair

I'm using Eclair and have a conf file with content:

```
eclair.chain=testnet
eclair.node-alias=mynodename
eclair.node-color=ff0000
eclair.api.enabled=true
eclair.server.public-ips=["<ip one>","<ip two>"]
eclair.api.password="my-eclair-api-pass"
eclair.bitcoind.rpcuser=aqaqaqaqaq
eclair.bitcoind.rpcpassword=aqaqaqaqaq
eclair.bitcoind.zmq="tcp://127.0.0.1:29000"
eclair.gui.unit=sat
```

still I can't see my node in https://explorer.acinq.co/
I can open channels

[Edit 1] My pubkey is 03125205d1b5ae747064491d2b3b30b41fd7ec4e96e0ccede2f71c55891995f675

Comment: Apparently my node is public at
https://1ml.com/testnet/node/03125205d1b5ae747064491d2b3b30b41fd7ec4e96e0ccede2f71c55891995f675

Comment: My pubkey is :
03125205d1b5ae747064491d2b3b30b41fd7ec4e96e0ccede2f71c55891995f675

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

- Lightning Network explorers are also nodes and just make their own "world view" of the network publicly available
- Your node will only become publicly visible once a channel has been opened and that information is announced to the network (and reaches the Explorer)
- Explorers do update irregularly, so it makes sense to give it some time and check multiple explores

Comment: if I want a channel be opened to my node, how to get my nodeID (QR code) in eclairMobile? I don't find the UI/setting for this